# UISlider for scrubbing the AQPlayer like iPod

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, avaudioplayer

**Can somebody tell me how to scrub the AQPlayer ( used in Apple's SpeakHere example ) using a UISlider like the iPod does?**

I know how to handle the slider part, but once I have my value from the slider, what do I need to set/change/update in AQPlayer, or the AudioQueue, so that the player moves to that part of the Queue and continues playing from that point?
Is there any easy way to do this with a percentage of the playing time or do I have to make some calculations with the packets??

Thanks for any input.
Al

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who also needs to seek/scrubb in an audio file, I found a solution to my question at the following link: [Audio Queues](http://www.idevgames.com/forums/printthread.php?tid=2538&page=3)

Have a look at the function

`-(void)seek:(UInt64)packetOffset;`

It worked perfectly after some initial fine tuning.